# KWStyle binary for Windows?

Tags: utility

I'm trying to install the [KWStyle](https://kitware.github.io/KWStyle/project/project.html) style-checker utility for C++ on Windows 7. I seem to be stumped at building it with my existing system.

Anyone know of an existing Windows binary for that tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was provided by request on a Github issue here:

https://github.com/Kitware/KWStyle/issues/101